# Add Searchview in listview and in listview data is coming from json

Tags: android, listview, full-text-search

I have list of cities in listview and now i want to add searchview in listview to search the item by specific letter like when i enter D in search view then all the cities should show with D in listview can anyone help me how can i do this i am new to android plaese help me.
this is my code in in this code only is showing in listview now i want to add searchview item please help

```
 public class CityNameActivity extends ListActivity {
ListView list;
EditText inputSearch;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
// URL to get Cities JSON
private static String url = "http://14.140.200.186/Hospital/get_city.php";
// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_CITIES = "Cities";
private static final String TAG_ID = "city_id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "city_name";
// Cities JSONArray
JSONArray Cities = null;
// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> citylist;
//ArrayList<String> citylist;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cityname_activity_main);
    ListView listView=getListView();
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    citylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    // list.setOnClickListener(this);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            String cityId= citylist.get(position).get(TAG_ID);
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    HospitalList_Activity.class);

            in.putExtra("city_id",cityId);
            startActivity(in);}
    });
    new GetCities().execute();
}
/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetCities extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CityNameActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                Cities = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CITIES);

                // looping through All Cities
                for (int i = 0; i < Cities.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = Cities.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    HashMap<String, String> Cities = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    Cities.put(TAG_ID, id);

                    Cities.put(TAG_NAME, name);



                    // adding contact to Cities list
                    citylist.add(Cities);


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**`enter code here`
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(CityNameActivity.this, citylist, R.layout.city_list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME}, new int[] { R.id.name});
        setListAdapter(adapter);




    }
}}
```

cityname_activity_main.xml

```
      <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

city_list_item.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```